# count results different tables single query mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the user `id_user=5` who has posts in three different tables

```
 questions (id_post | id_user ...)    (7 posts)
 marketplace (id_post | id_user ...)  (9 posts)
 jobs (id_post | id_user ...)         (3 posts)
```

So I want to count, using a single query, the number of posts he has in each table

This is what I have so far...but it doesnt seems to work

```
 (SELECT 
  COUNT(p.*) as count_questions 
   FROM $table_questions as p
  WHERE p.id_user = :id_user1 
  )
 UNION
 (
SELECT 
 COUNT(m.*) as count_marketplace
 FROM $table_marketplace as m
  WHERE  m.id_user = :id_user2
  )
 UNION
 (SELECT 
 COUNT(e.*) as count_jobs
 FROM $table_jobs as e
  WHERE  e.id_user = :id_user3 

  )
```

**what am doing wrong?**

I was expecting to retrieve in php like this

```
   $count_questions = $result["count_questions"];
```

but it doesnt seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(id_user) as counter
FROM $table_questions WHERE id_user = :id_user1 
UNION
SELECT COUNT(id_user) as counter
FROM $table_marketplace WHERE id_user = :id_user2
UNION
SELECT COUNT(id_user) as counter
FROM $table_jobs WHERE id_user = :id_user3
```

Will return 3 rows each with the count, you have to give all the counts the same alias.

If you want to maybe identfy each result row specifically add another column as an identifier

```
SELECT 'Questions' as what, COUNT(id_user) as counter
FROM $table_questions WHERE id_user = :id_user1 
UNION
SELECT 'Marketplace' as what, COUNT(id_user) as counter
FROM $table_marketplace WHERE id_user = :id_user2
UNION
SELECT 'Jobs' as what, COUNT(id_user) as counter
FROM $table_jobs WHERE id_user = :id_user3
```

Will give something like

```
what            count
Questions       7
Marketplace     9
Jobs            3
```

And you can retrieve them as

```
$array = $stmt->fetch_all();
```

You will get an array like

```
Array
(
    [Questions] => 7
    [Marketplace] => 9
    [Jobs] => 3
)
```

Comment: ok. thank you. I see the point here. but how do I relate "Q" with the first "count" field when retrieving, and so on.

Comment: Call it anything you like, so if you want, call them `Questions` and `Marketplace` and `Jobs`

Comment: Ok Thank you. I do see the point. but actually cant get the results as you do. $counts = $sql>fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $count_jobs=$counts["Jobs"]["counter"]; it doesnt retrieve me any value

Comment: I showed you how to get the results... `$array = $stmt->fetch_all();`